# SQL query I need to populate 1 return value from possible values in 3 columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need query to return one value based on possible values in 3 different columns.  Only 1 of the 3 columns will be greater than 0. I'm having problems creating the query.

Table:

```
FIELDA    FIELDB    FIELDC   FIELDD    FIELDE 
---------------------------------------------
Plastic   Blue      0        10        0 
Plastic   Blue      10       0         0 
Plastic   Blue      0        0         20
```

Query something like:

```
select 
    FieldA, FieldB,
    (If FieldC > 0 then 'We Have C'
    else if FieldD > 0 then 'We Have D'
    else if FieldE > 0 then 'We Have E'
    end if
    ) as WeHave
from 
    ThingsWeHave
```

I would like return results to be.

```
FieldA     FieldB     WeHave
---------------------------------
Plastic    Blue       We Have D
Plastic    Blue       We Have C   
Plastic    Blue       We Have E
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a `case` statement:

```
select FieldA, FieldB,
       (case when FieldC > 0 then 'We Have C'
             when FieldD > 0 then 'We Have D'
             when FieldE > 0 then 'We Have E'
        end) as WeHave
from ThingsWeHave;
```

However, I answered this to point out how you can include multiple "things" in the column:

```
select FieldA, FieldB,
       ((case when FieldC > 0 then 'We Have C; ' else '' end) +
        (case when FieldD > 0 then 'We Have D; ' else '' end) +
        (case when FieldE > 0 then 'We Have E; ' else '' end)
       ) as WeHave
from ThingsWeHave;
```

This isn't exactly your question, but it might be useful.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for and thank you for the additional example.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CASE WHEN` expression.

```
SELECT FieldA, FieldB,
       CASE
           WHEN FieldC > 0 THEN 'We have C'
           WHEN FieldD > 0 THEN 'We have D'
           WHEN FieldE > 0 THEN 'We have E'
       END as WeHave
FROM ThingsWeHave
```

You only need one `CASE WHEN` statement if only one field will be nonzero at the same time.